# How do I get a picture of the entire schema with liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I'm using liquibase in a dropwizard project. From the dropwizard docs, I see that I can run something along the lines of:

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db generate-docs helloworld.yml ~/db-docs/
```

and that will generate some html docs for the existing schema. However, the pages that it generates are not very usable. They do not contain foreign key constraints, and the formatting makes it difficult to determine what a table looks like at a glance.

I'm used to viewing my schema as a single .sql file, with blocks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (
    int row1,
    text row2,
)
// key and index information
```

What do other people who use liquibase do to get an overview of the current state of their schema and plan changes? Are there options that I missed to configure the liquibase output? Do you use another tool to look at the current state of your project's schema?

Thanks for any tips or tricks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using Liquibase to manage your database changes, there is no reason you cannot continue using whatever tools you prefer to view the state of the database and plan those changes.

Besides dbdoc (which generate-docs calls), Liquibase supports a "snapshot" command which outputs a simple report of the objects in the schema and "generateChangeLog" command which outputs all the the current schema objects as changeSets. I'm not sure how/if either command is exposed through dropwizard. Neither will give you an SQL output, however, since Liquibase is targeted at applying changes, not visualizing the database.